# How do you prevent a Menu Bar (Agent) macos app from unchecking the boxes when running in the background?

Tags: swift, xcode, menubar

I'm new to Swift and need some guidance with a relatively easy task.

I have created a macos menu bar app that plays some audio. The methods I used are all pretty straightforward, setting outlets and actions for different buttons. It works perfectly, but when I minimize it (the NSPopover behaviour is set to transient) the audio stops playing and all the parameters are reset as soon as I hover with the cursor over the menu bar.

Thanks in advance.

CODE
This is my ViewController.swift file:

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController {


@IBOutlet  var neapolitancheck: NSButton!

@IBOutlet  var neapolitanslider: NSSliderCell!




var neapolitanaudio = AVAudioPlayer()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    neapolitanslider.doubleValue  = 0



    // sound file
    let neapolitansound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NeapolitanNeighbours", ofType: "mp3")

    do {
        //try to get to initialize the sound just created
        neapolitanaudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: neapolitansound!))

    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {


    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}





@IBAction func neapolitanplayer(_ sender: Any) {

    if (neapolitanaudio.isPlaying == true) {
        neapolitanaudio.stop()
        //neapolitanslider.doubleValue = 0
    }
    else {
        neapolitanaudio.play()
       // neapolitanaudio.numberOfLoops = -1
      //  neapolitanslider.doubleValue = 0.15
      //  neapolitanaudio.volume = neapolitanslider.floatValue
    }
}
```

And this is the AppDelegate:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {




let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)




func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    statusItem.button?.title = "⏚"
    statusItem.button?.target = self
    statusItem.button?.action = #selector(showSettings)


}


func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application


}

@objc func showSettings() {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as?
        ViewController else {
            fatalError("Unable to find ViewController in the storyboard")
    }

    guard let button = statusItem.button else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find statuItem button.")
    }

    let popoverView = NSPopover()
    popoverView.contentViewController = vc
    popoverView.behavior = .transient
    popoverView.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: .maxY)
    popoverView.animates = true




}
```

}

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Sorry about the omission